# should I make an attribute as primary key in sql server or should I check in the servlet?

Tags: sql-server, jsp, servlets

I have one teacher_details table that has `teacher_id` as the primary key and one exam_details table which has exam_id as one attribute.

I want one teacher can't create the same exam_id more than one time but it can be possible that 2 teachers can create the same exam_id.

Should I make exam_id as the primary key or I will check that in the servlet?

I am using sql-server for database.

```
create table teacher_details(
teacher_id varchar(20) not null primary key,
teacher_name varchar(30));

create table exam_details(exam_id varchar(20), exam_name varchar(30), teacher_id varchar(20), foreign key (teacher_id) references teachers_details(teacher_id));
```

Comment: Do it the reverse way,exam_id in teacher_details table and you need to have the API configured to handle the same.

Comment: What API configured?

Comment: I mean it should be handled at servlet level as well!

Answer (score 1):

You should make the combination of `exame_id` and `teacher_id` the primary key of your `exam_details` table.
Also, you should get used to naming your constraints:

```
create table teacher_details
(
    teacher_id varchar(20) not null,
    teacher_name varchar(30),
    constraint pk_teacher_details primary key (teacher_id)
);

create table exam_details (
    exam_id varchar(20), 
    exam_name varchar(30), 
    teacher_id varchar(20), 
    constraint fk_teacher_exam foreign key (teacher_id) references teacher_details(teacher_id),
    constraint pk_exam_details primary key (teacher_id, exam_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check this in servlet, because if you make exam_id as primary key, than two teachers would not be able to create the same exam_id

Comment: I disagree. This is clearly a data integrity issue, and as such should be handled by the database.

Comment: I'm just saying that he wants different teachers to create the same exam_id, if he make it a primary key in database, it will be impossible

Comment: A primary key can be composed of multiple columns, as my answer shows. If the primary key is a composite one, there is no problem at all with this demand.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can u please explain how to approach for handling by database through composite primary key

Comment: @DmytroGrynets, I think approaching through servlet will be an easier approach but still want to know how to handle by database using composite primary key

Comment: @dinesh I dont understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually, I want to make a project where at first teacher will fill a registration form and then he/she can fill a form for exam details after logging into the account. 
I was making the tables in the database for that and here finding the problem. Problem occurring when assigning teacher_user_id of exam_details as foreign key referencing the teacher_user_id of teacher_details. I also want 1 teacher can create different exam_id and at the same time each exam_id can also be created by different teacher